# How to limit img max width everywhere?

Tags: css, vuetify.js

I am building an app with Vuejs and I include html from outside of my app with the `v-html` tag

So basically it's `<v-card-text v-html="article.t">`

The problem I have is that sometimes the `<img>` in the included `html` is too big. I want to limit it's width.

```
<style>
.guardian img {
  width:50% !important;
  max-width:200px !important; 
}
.gu-image {
  width:50% !important;
  max-width:200px !important; 
}
</style>
```

But it doesn't work. My question is: How to control the img width everywhere on the page?

Comment: `img {max-width: XXXpx}`

Comment: doesnt work all the time

Comment: where is you generated html?

Comment: inside the v-card-text

Comment: Well, what does the `img` tag look like? Does it have other classes that override your css?

Comment: @Traxo, the difficulty is that I don't have control over what's inside the img tag because i'm getting it from outside of my app. Can I still control my img width?

Comment: Am I misunderstanding something? You are using `v-html` to display `img`, thus img is inside of your app, so you can style it.

Comment: @Traxo correct. but it seems that the styling doesnt work on the img inside the v-html

Comment: I believe it must work. Can you reproduce on [codepen](https://template.vuetifyjs.com)? Or perhaps you are using `<style scoped>` and targeting nested elements? Can you confirm that style is not applied to the element? It might be applied but no effect in case you made some CSS mistake. Hard to say without more info.

Comment: @Traxo I did use style scoped... It solved the problem! Thanks